# C++ - Why I cannot debugging in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I am using Xcode Version 7.3.1. I already have experience programming in C and Python. Now, I am learning programming in C++. At the same time, I am trying to understand the use of IDE since before this I am just using the terminal.

So, I was told about the step into, step over etc. features of debugging. In Xcode, I can access this by clicking the `Debug` tab at the top. But all the selections of this debugging can't be accessed (it is all greyed out). Why is this? How can I fix this?

To better illustrate this, I put a screenshot of what I meant about.[image]

Comment: Have you actually started your program in the debugger? If you're not running in the debugger, how can you e.g. step over a statement?

Comment: Indeed; put a breakpoint inside `main()` and step-away.